# Lookahead/behind in non-perl style regex?

Tags: regex, grep

Is there any way to look ahead/behind for a substring without using `initial(?!.*(substring))`? i.e., how can you search for "initial" and then remove any matches that have "substring" anywhere after it with a regular expression if you don't have access to perl?

Comment: Many other regex-implementations support these too (Python, `grep -P`, …), what do you specifically mean by not having access to perl?

Comment: I mean without using the Perl syntax. Just using the regex that works with egrep for example.

Comment: Believe it or not, before perl gave us look-behinds, `grep foo | grep -v bar` was perfectly normal. Some people might have used `awk /foo/ && !/bar/` instead. Don't be ashamed of using two regexps to do the job.

Answer (score 0):

If you search for two matches: (1) `initial` and (2) `initial.*substring`, then based on those two results you know if there is such match or not. If first match is found and second not, then your string contains "*initial*" with no "*substring*" ahead...

Comment: Yes, but the problem is getting the lines that don't have the substring after initial as the output. I need the output of egrep -v "initial.*substring", but I'm looking for a solution via regex only.

Comment: @stariz77 - So? Go with `grep initial file.txt | grep -v initial.*substring`